# Android Espresso FlakyTest annotation - how to filter tests on execution?

Tags: android, android-espresso

From what i read from these [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/filters/FlakyTest.html)  we can annotate any flakytests and then there should be a way to filter them out and run them alone.I was thinking firebase robo tests will know about this and re -tests the flaky ones only, but the following statements have confused me :

> Can then be used to filter tests on execution using -e annotation or -e notAnnotation as desired.

What is this switch **-e** ? How can i filter tests ? the comment leads me to confusion on how to fitler tests on execution. is it done on the gradle command line ? Can i get an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enter code hereI finally found out how to do this.  When you put annotations on test methods you can run a group of methods that have the same annotation. Reading [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner.html) we find out how to do this.  so if i were to mark many tests as @FlakyTest then i can run all of the FlakyTest with adb like this:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e annotation android.support.test.filters.FlakyTest
```

Here is an the part of the AndroidJUnitRunner docs explaining this:

> Filter test run to tests with given annotation: adb shell am instrument -w -e annotation com.android.foo.MyAnnotation com.android.foo/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner

Comment: but its deprecated since API level 24, check this out https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/FlakyTest.html

Comment: Thanks for responding.your looking at the old one which is deprecated. the old FlakyTest that took tolerance parameter is deprecated in favor of  this one :https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/filters/FlakyTest.html . my answer already has a link to this. your looking at the deprecated annotation. im providing link to the replacement.

Comment: You can also create custom annotations and filter for them. Check [this](https://medium.com/@evanfang/run-specific-android-espresso-tests-by-creating-custom-annotations-using-kotlin-and-command-line-6a90e8728e3b) or [this](https://medium.com/@mohitgupta92/creating-custom-annotations-for-android-espresso-tests-56388025d637) article for detailed explanation.